# Meaning of "then-current price" in a Subscription Renewal Contract

Tags: licensing, definition

[Section 5.3 of the Unity Terms of Service says that a subscription "will automatically renew at the then-current list price."](https://unity.com/legal/terms-of-service#:%7E:text=will%20automatically%20renew%20at%20the%20then%2Dcurrent%20list%20price) When does "then-current" refer to in this context?

Comment: I'm asking because my [first](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/then-current) [two](https://grammarhow.com/better-ways-to-say-then-current/) (which seem to be the only relevant) search results give contradicting answers.

Comment: Two part answer below - one with my own interpretations and paraphrasing directly from my father's statements and examples (from his 50 years experience as a lawyer - which he's still doing at the time of these posts!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer - I'm an IT Security guy who also does consulting on the side.  This first section is my interpretation with my understanding of contracts based on those I've issued with similar clauses.**

I'm fairly certain that this would be interpreted as "The list price at the time the right to renew the subscription is used by Unity" - i.e. if the price for a subscription was initially $10/month and then it went up to $15/month after you accepted the ToS, then unless you've cancelled your subscription you will be auto-billed at $15/month when the subscription auto-renew comes up.

(Mods/Reviewers: This is an answer repost because other views of this page were NOT updating with my edits - I don't normally delete-and-repost, but when SE's platform decides to be weird...)

---

**Disclaimer: This section here is based directly off of my asking my dad who was a lawyer for ~50 years on legal interpretation of the wording of the ToS snippet included verbatim.  The following is paraphrasing of his direct statements in the discussion he and I had over lunch.**

I checked also with my dad who's been a lawyer (working white collar criminal defense, contract law, and mediations focusing on corporate contracts and civil cases) for nearly 50 years.  The current legal interpretation of this phrasing is essentially what my own interpretation is:

> With the context of a subscription service renewal, the 'then-current' price is the price of renewal at the time the renewal would happen.  That is, if your subscription was at $100/month, but then the subscription rate is now $150/month at the time of renewal, the legal-interpreted 'then-current' list price is $150/month.

Additionally, he stated there were similar clauses in the contract/engagement agreements between him and clients with hourly rate agreements and engagement letters.  Which is the legal interpretation of 'then-current rate'.